# android app crash due to memory alloc error while using fragment with drawable resource (jpg)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've just started android programming.

So I followed an example video online showing swipe views.  I learned these concepts and tested the program on my phone; Works fine.

The program uses a ViewPager and a FragmentPagerAdapter to switch between each fragment.

So I expanded the fragment code (which just displayed a blank fragment with a solid colour), to display an image:

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1_layout, container, false);
    ImageView   imgView  = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.causeway1);
    return rootView;
    }
}
```

I get the message "unfortunately mytestapp has stopped" when I debug the app on my phone.

I haven't been successful in deploying an emulator on my PC, so I have to use my phone (a Samsung galaxy note 3).

The error from logcat says java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, indicating the setImageResource line.  The image is 906kb in size.  Is that too large?

What kind of memory restrictions are there on the android platform - and is there any way to ask for more, or should I try to resample my images down to smaller size?

Comment: how many frags did you have at the moment

Comment: just 3.  Image 1 is 304k, image 2 is 906k, image3 is 172k

Answer (score 1):

I removed the call to create the bitmap at 906k with one of the smaller ones, and my app worked.

I found the following in logcat output, which I suspect may be to blame:

```
Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (5760x3240, max=4096x4096)
```

Comment: can confirm that resizing the image in photoshop solved my problem.  But the largest image size was 1920x1080; so why was bitmap considered too large ?